# Relative entropy for martingale measures

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, entropy, local-martingales

I need some help understanding a note given in a lot of papers I've read.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a complete probability Space, $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ a given filtration with usual conditions, $S$ be a locally bounded semi-martingale and $$M_a = \{ Q \ll P \; | \; S \text{ is a locale } (Q,\mathbb{F})-\text{martingale}\}$$ the set of all absolutely continuous martingale measures.

Now I found a lot of papers claiming it's natural to assume that the set
$$M_e = \{ Q \in M_a \; | \; H[Q|P] < +\infty \}$$

is non empty where

$$H[Q|P] = \begin{cases}
        E_P\Big[\frac{dQ}{dP}\log\frac{dQ}{dP}\Big] & \mbox{ if }Q \ll P \\
        +\infty  & \mbox{ otherwise}
         \end{cases} $$

is the relative entropy of $Q$ w.r.t $P$.

But I see no reason why $M_e \not= \emptyset$ should hold.

Maybe someone has a hint or link for me.

edit 09.12.2019: To point out my main issue here (see comments to second answer): It's totally clear to me why the set $M_a$ of absolutely continuous (locale) martingale measures is not empty if we have an arbitrage free (in the NFLVR sense) market. But why does at least one of these measures have a finite entropy related to our initial measure $P$?

Greetings

Comment: I don't want to seem too precise, but what is the exact definition of a "locally bounded" semi-martingale?

Comment: $S$ is a semi-martingale that is locally bounded so there exists a localizing sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of $\mathbb{F}$ stopping times  s.t. $S^{\tau_n}$ is uniformly bounded in $t\in [0,T]$.

Answer (score 7):

$M_e$ contains $P$, because $P\in M_a$ and $\frac{dP}{dP}=1$ and therefore $H[P|P]=0.$

I will show that $M_e$ contains more than just $P$ in the case where $S$ is a Brownian motion.
In that case, Girsanov's theorem tells us that the elements in $M_a$ are the probability measures $Q$ under which $S$ is a Brownian motion with an added continuous drift $b$, and that $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ satisfies
$\frac{dQ}{dP}=D_T$,
where
\begin{equation*}
D_t = \exp\bigg(
\int^t_0b(u)dS_u - \tfrac{1}{2}\int^t_0 b(u)^2 du
\bigg)
\end{equation*}
for any $t\in[0,T]$,
under the condition that $D$ is a martingale. 
One sufficient condition that $D$ is a martingale is the Novikov condition, which requires that
\begin{equation*}
E_P\bigg[\exp\bigg(\tfrac{1}{2}\int^T_0 b(u)^2 du\bigg)\bigg]<\infty.
\end{equation*}
If $D$ is a martingale,
then substitution of $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ in the relative entropy yields
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E_P\bigg[\frac{dQ}{dP}\log\frac{dQ}{dP}\bigg]
=
E_Q\bigg[\log\frac{dQ}{dP}\bigg]
&=
E_Q\bigg[\int^T_0 b(u)dS_u\bigg]
-
E_Q\bigg[\tfrac{1}{2}\int^T_0 b(u)^2 du\bigg]
\\
&=
E_P\bigg[\int^T_0 b(u)dS_u\bigg]
+
E_Q\bigg[\tfrac{1}{2}\int^T_0 b(u)^2 du\bigg]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
(note in the last equality the one change of measure from $Q$ to $P$)
where it is used that $S$ is a Brownian motion plus drift $b$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},Q)$.
If $b$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
E_Q\bigg[\int^T_0 b(u)^2 du\bigg]<\infty,
\end{equation*}
then the stochastic integral $\int^T_0 b(u)dS_u$ will have zero expectation,
and it follows that $H[Q|P]$ is finite.

You might find the following article interesting: http://jbierkens.nl/pubs/2014-scl.pdf It considers the above in more detail and in the context of control theory, where the drift $b$ acts as a control and $H[Q|P]$ as a control cost.

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for your answer. I have two notes about it. 1.) Why should $P\in \mathcal{M}_a$ hold? In general S is a P-semi martingale but not a P-local martingale, so in general $P\not\in\mathcal{M}_a$. Or is there anything I didn't get? 2.) I already know that there a some cases (e.g. Levy processes) where the minimal equivalent martingale measure can be constructed explictly and then it's clear that this measure is a (local) martingale measure with finite entropy. But it wasn't clear for me for the general case. So the question were posted for this purpose :-) But again: Thx a lot!

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that about 1.) Thanks for pointing that out. I'm sorry, I see my answer doesn't really add much now.

Answer (score 2):

> In general S is a P-semi martingale but not a P-local martingale, so in general $P∉M_a.$

A local martingale is a martingale if and only if it is of class (DL)

> But I see no reason why $M_e≠∅$ should hold

Usually we consider the set non empty by assumption; moreover, the set $M_e$ is not, in general, a singleton, so we are typically left with

[image]

Edit:

> This is always stated but as mentioned in my question it was said to be "natural". For me this means that somehow there is a justification why this should hold. Do you have one?

Yes, it is reasonable to make such an assumption, and the justification is quite practical: here is a pic from the book *Mathematical Finance - Bachelier Congress 2000 (selected Papers from the First World Congress of the Bachelier Finance Society, Paris, June 29-July 1, 2000)*, p. 430

[image]
[image]

Edit (II): I found this, maybe can help:

[image]

Moreover,

[image]

However, I leave here the link, where the topic is analyzed in more detail: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1029867119

---

Edit 10-12-2019

[image]

(source: http://cfmar2017.pstat.ucsb.edu/talks/Frittelli.pdf)

But we already know this, so the question is

> why does at least one of these measures have a finite entropy related to our initial measure P?

[image]

This abstract is taken from a paper by Marco Frittelli: *The Minimal Entropy Martingale Measure and the Valuation Problem in Incomplete Markets*. I've not explored the rest of the article, so I'm not sure whether Frittelli explains or not the reasons you are looking for. Nevertheless, if you are interested here is the paper: http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/frittelli/pdf/EntropyMF2000.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware that $M_e$ is not a singleton in general. You said "*Usually we consider the set non empty by assumption*".  This is always stated but as mentioned in my question it was said to be "natural". For me this means that somehow there is a justification why this should hold. Do you have one?

Comment: @Gono Got it, now I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you again. I've read a lot of Schachermayer's papers to this topic, also the given sources [DS 94] and [DS 98a] before. The problem is, that also in the book the definition of $\mathcal{M}^e(S)$ is slightly different. It does not contain the restriction of a finite relative entropy!
So it's totally clear why the set of equivalent (locale) martingale measures is not empty if we have an arbitrage free (in the NFLVR sense) market . But why does at least one of these have a finite entropy? This is actually my key question.

Comment: @Gono After doing some more research, I found this article https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1029867119

Comment: There it's just said that IF the set above in non-empty but no justification for it… again :-(

Comment: @Gono last edit, am not sure though if this may help

Comment: Thank you. Although I've read most of Fritellis papers already I will read it… not sure if it helps. But not to waste my bounty and to reward your work I will give it to you (and start a next run in a few month…)

Comment: Thank you very much! Since now I'm interested in the topic too, please let me know if you find any answer!